# Fetch data from drop down using sweet alert

Tags: angular6, sweetalert2

How to get value of selected value using Html property when i clieck on OK.

```
changeStatus(row) {
    debugger;
    swal({
        title: 'Change Status',
        text: txt,
        html: '<label class=" control-label" style="margin-top: 4px;"></label><select style="margin-left: -51%;"class="swal2-select id="dropdown"><option value="Certified">Certified</option> <option value="Registered">Registered</option> <option value="Processed">Processed</option></select><br>' + '<b style="margin-left: -84%;">Remarks </b><br>' +
            '<textarea id="text" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>',
        showCancelButton: true,
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            debugger;
            row.Notes = document.getElementById('text'),
            row.Notes = row.Notes.value;

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
swal({
      title: 'Select Type',
      input: 'select',
      inputOptions: {
       'CERT': 'Certified',
       'REG': 'Registered',
       'PROC': 'Processed'
      },
      inputPlaceholder: 'Select Type',
      showCancelButton: true,
      inputValidator: function (value) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
         if (value === 'REG') {
           resolve('');
         } else {
           reject('You need to select type:)');
         }
      })
    }
    }).then(function (result) {
     swal({
        type: 'success',
        html: 'You selected: ' + result
        })
      });
```

Comment: How can i get dropdown value